# Can I convert this into length all at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

This is some part of the JSON. There are other data where the `selected` genre is book. Hence, I wanted to have an example of how to filter the `Movie` and count the length of the `genre` too.

```
const data = [{
      "1": { drama: { Comedy: true, Romance: true } },
      "2": {
        drama2: { Tragedy: true}
        others: "Dystopian",
      },
      id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",
      genre: {
        selected: "Movie",
      },
      displayName: "p1"
    }, 
     {
      "1": { drama: { Tragedy: true } },
      "2": {
        drama2: { Romance: true}
      },
      id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93", //sample id
      genre: {
        selected: "Movie",
      },
      displayName: "p2"
    }]

 const drama = data.filter(
    (v) => v.genre?.selected == "Movie"
  )
  
  const comedy = drama.filter(
    (a) =>
    a["1"]?.drama.Comedy == true
  );

  const romance = drama.filter(
    (a) =>
    a["1"]?.drama.Romance == true
  );

   const tragedy = drama.filter(
        (a) =>
        a["1"]?.drama.Tragedy == true
      );
```

Is there a way where I could turn the `comedy`, `romance`, and `tragedy` into a length all at once rather than something like this?

```
  let n = comedy.length
  console.log(n)
```

Comment: _"I'm sorry for the post earlier. Hence, I wanted to create another post."_ - You're free to delete your questions. If you ask the same question again then make this a stand-alone question and don't reference [earlier versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69204430/can-i-convert-this-into-length-all-at-one) or expect every reader to know that there was a earlier version and its content.

Comment: I'm not sure I am even getting what you are actually trying to ask here. Is this _just_ about avoiding that extra step of accessing `comedy.length`? Then go with a solution that uses [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of filter.

Comment: You're not accessing the `1` field of your objects correctly. It should be `a[1]?.drama`. The `.` behind `[]` is invalid syntax. After that you should be able to access `.length` on your filtered arrays.

Comment: @CBroe yes, I just wanted to know if there are other ways and such

Comment: @Wing Thanks, I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes, use `reduce` then. `filter` currently still creates a new array, so that you need to get the length of that afterwards. But if you are not actually interested in the items, and _only_ in their count - then `reduce` can help you create an integer value right away, without the "intermediate" step of creating a filtered array.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I only wanted to get the count of each of the genre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object, `counts`, containing the count for each genre.

```js
const data = [{
  "1": { drama: { Comedy: true, Romance: true, BuddyComedy: false } },
  "2": {
    drama2: { Tragedy: true},
    others: "Dystopian",
  },
  id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",
  genre: {
    selected: "Movie",
  },
  displayName: "p1"
}, 
 {
  "1": { drama: { Tragedy: true } },
  "2": {
    drama2: { Romance: true}
  },
  id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93", //sample id
  genre: {
    selected: "Movie",
  },
  displayName: "p2"
}]

const movies = data.filter(v => v.genre?.selected == "Movie");
const counts = movies.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return Object.entries(cur["1"].drama).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => { 
        if (value) { 
            acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + 1;
        }
        return acc;
    }, acc)
}, {})

console.log('Counts:', counts)
```